# A superclass reference shouldn't be able to call methods exclusive to it's subclass but

Tags: java, inheritance

But, if the superclass has an abstract method, and that method is implemented in it's subclass, which is concrete, we will still be able to call the subclass' implementation of the method using an Object of the superclass.

How come?

Same for overloaded methods, the subclass' implementation is called even though you call it using a reference of the superclass.

Let me be more specific here...

Suppose Animal is a superclass and Dog is a subclass.
Now, I do:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

What this means is that a is a reference to an animal class, right?

Now, if I do, a.function(); (assume that the function is defined in Animal and overridden in Dog), the Animal's version ought to be called as a is a reference to an animal, but it's the other way around.

Comment: Because it's not exclusive to the subclass?

Comment: That's the whole point of abstract methods and polymorphism... that the *caller* doesn't need to know the details of the implementation...

Comment: Overloading is not the same as overriding. Taking the edit into account, I don't know anymore what your question is about.

Comment: `Animal a = new Dog();` Is `a` a reference to Animal object or a Dog object?

Comment: It's a reference to a Dog object.

Comment: So, it's a reference of type `Animal` but points to a `Dog` object, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It means that a super class cannot call methods that are defined in sub classes because the super class doesn't know them. For abstract methods, the super class is aware of them so it can call them. This also happens with non-abstract and non-final methods: they can be modified by the sub class without noticing the super class, and the super class may still work with no problems.

What you're describing is the difference between compile time and execution time (also called run time). At compile time, a variable can only call methods defined on the type the variable is declared e.g. `Animal animal` then `animal` variable can only call methods that are defined in `Animal` class. At execution time, the execution of the method will be handled by the class that belongs to the instance of the object reference e.g. `Animal animal = new Dog();` then `animal` behavior will be defined by the behavior stated in `Dog` class.

Example:

```
public class Animal {
    abstract void breath();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void breath() {
        System.out.println("Dog breathing");
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("woof!");
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //animal variable is of type Animal
        //and initialized as a Dog object reference
        Animal animal = new Dog();

        //dog variable is of type Dog (also an Animal)
        //and initialized as a Dog object reference
        Dog dog = new Dog();

        animal.breath();
        dog.breath();

        //line below throws a compiler exception
        //since animal is declared as type Animal
        //not all Animals know how to bark
        animal.bark();

        //line below compiles fine
        //since dog is declared as type Dog
        //and Dog's know how to bark
        dog.bark();
    }
}
```